# Allow only [a-z][A-Z][0-9] in string using PHP

Tags: php, regex

How can I get a string that only contains a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9 and some symbols?

Comment: Please give more details.  What is your need?

Comment: It's a hazy question but there is no need to downvote it into oblivion. There are *really* bad questions around that could use that sort of treatment, but this one is not one of them.

Comment: my string is ��S�o�n�u� �N�i�g�a�m�,� �S�a�i�n�d�h�a�v�i.

i would like to eliminate the symbols...

Comment: use like this,

$strchr = "��S�o�n�u� �N�i�g�a�m�,� �S�a�i�n�d�h�a�v�i";
$bodytag = str_replace("�", "", $strchr);

Comment: nice it works...
that was already worked...
i just restart my mozilla...
i got it..

thanks a lot to all...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can test your string (let `$str`) using `preg_match`:

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $str) == 1) {
    // string only contain the a to z , A to Z, 0 to 9
}
```

If you need more symbols you can add them before `]`

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should have to surround the pattern in `^` and `$` to prevent match to `'??abs??'` for example, and the whole with `/` delimiters. Sorry & thanks.

Answer (score 30):

You can filter it like:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $text);
```

As for ***some symbols***, you should be ***more*** specific

Answer (score 12):

Don't need regex, you can use the [`Ctype`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php) functions:

- [`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php): Check for alphanumeric character(s)
- [`ctype_alpha`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php): Check for alphabetic character(s)
- [`ctype_cntrl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-cntrl.php): Check for control character(s)
- [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php): Check for numeric character(s)
- [`ctype_graph`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-graph.php): Check for any printable character(s) except space
- [`ctype_lower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-lower.php): Check for lowercase character(s)
- [`ctype_print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-print.php): Check for printable character(s)
- [`ctype_punct`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-punct.php): Check for any printable character which is not whitespace or an alphanumeric character
- [`ctype_space`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php): Check for whitespace character(s)
- [`ctype_upper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-upper.php): Check for uppercase character(s)
- [`ctype_xdigit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-xdigit.php): Check for character(s) representing a hexadecimal digit

In your case use `ctype_alnum`, example:

```
if (ctype_alnum($str)) {
    //...
}
```

Example:

```
<?php
$strings = array('AbCd1zyZ9', 'foo!#$bar');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_alnum($testcase)) {
        echo 'The string ', $testcase, ' consists of all letters or digits.';
    } else {
        echo 'The string ', $testcase, ' don\'t consists of all letters or digits.';

    }
}
```

Online example: https://ideone.com/BYN2Gn

Answer (score 1):

Both these regexes should do it:

```
$str = preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9]+~i', '', $str);
```

Or:

```
$str = preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z0-9]+~', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut will be as below also:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\w\.]+$/', $str)) {
    echo 'Str is valid and allowed';
} else
    echo 'Str is invalid';
```

Here:

```
// string only contain the a to z , A to Z, 0 to 9 and _ (underscore)
\w - matches [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve spaces in your string do this

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/", "", $text);
```

Please note the way I have added space between 9 and the closing bracket. For example

```
$name = "!#$John Doe";
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/", "", $name);
```

the output will be:
`John Doe`

Spaces in the string will be preserved.

If you fail to include the space between 9 and the closing bracket the output will be:

`JohnDoe`

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

The best and most flexible way to accomplish that is using regular expressions.
But I`m not sure how to do that in PHP but this article can help. [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)