# How to check if string contains anything but QWERY/1234

Tags: php

I'm trying to make sure a string I'm posting only has alphabetical and numberical letters/numbers + ,.; etc. However all checks I seem to do still bring back à è ò as valid?

Anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of your current check that is not working?

Comment: Well I've been checking for UTF8, but I've realised that atually these charaters are UTF8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know *exactly* what characters you want to allow, a [regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) should be fitting your needs:

```php
// matches exactly the characters you asked for, no more
preg_match(/[a-zA-Z0-9,\.;]*/, $your_string);
```

Be sure to escape [meta characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php), because for example a non-escaped dot (.) will match *every character*.

Comment: I've updated it to "^/[a-zA-Z0-9\;\'\,\.\;]*/"

But when I try the string asdgdfgsasdf.,;'; ir returns false, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding the `$` anchor: `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\.;']+$/"`

Comment: Seems to me you don't have to escape ";", "'" and "," because they do not have a meta character meaning. And you must start and end with the same character ("/" normally), "^" must be inside the "/"s (see cOle2's regex).

Comment: cOle2, tried your one, but still bringing back false :/ 

Dominik I'm not too familair with regular expressions, so this is proving difficult to udnerstand

Comment: Excluding the pattern delimiter `/`, you don't need to escape any character in brace (nor `-` if it is at the end of the char list) so `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9,;:.'-]*$/"` will work.

Comment: cOle2's regex works for me (at least for the string you posted). Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2896450/1168892) could help you more (google showed it to me :) ).

Comment: OH £@£$@£%£$, had my expression and $str the wrong way around! Haha, thanks for the help guys!