# How to check if any character has been typed which is not allowed with php

Tags: php, html

Suppose I have a form and in the form, there is an input field for the users to put their full names. I want only characters (A-Za-z) and spaces to be submitted by the users.

```
<form action='page2.php'>
    <input type='text' name='fullname'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

I know, it can be done by html. But I want to check in page2 if user has typed anything without (A-Za-z) and spaces. How this check can be performed with php?

Comment: Regex, or perhaps [ctype_alpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only \[a-z\]\[A-Z\]\[0-9\] in string using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896450/allow-only-a-za-z0-9-in-string-using-php)

Comment: you can use `str_pos()`

Comment: `Basil d'Olivera` is a full name with blocked characters; as is `Tim Berners-Lee`, or names like `José` or `Étienne` or `François` [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: The area where the website is available, people have names only with A-Za-z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $user)) {
    /// not match
}
```

Comment: You are missing a + or * after the square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Regex is big for this kind of tasks.
You can use this :

```
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $name)) === false)  {
  $errors[] = 'Name must contain letters and spaces only';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use regex then below is the code to check alphabet only

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $string);
```