# PHP regex a-Z 0-9 () and []

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex, so I've done a bit research.
My filter should only allow:

- a-Z
- 0-9 (meaning 0 to 9)
- ()
- []

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896450/allow-only-a-za-z0-9-in-string-using-php) regex:

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/"
```

I edited it to allow ()

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9()]+$/"
```

But how to make the regex allowing [] too? Seems like [] need to be escaped somehow.

Comment: yes it needs to be escaped

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The character `\` is the escape character in regex. Try this:

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9()\[\]]+$/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to escape the square brackets if you put them first, like so:

```
^[][a-zA-Z0-9()]+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uH5Kgp/2).
*Please also note that `a-Z` is not the same as `a-zA-Z`, see [**the famous answer from @Wiktor here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926) for more details.*